# Error when running npm install on an Angular project

Tags: angular, npm

I am running this command in an Angular project but I get this error, I tried to delete the `node_modules/` folder but I still get the error.

```
$ npm install --force
npm WARN using --force Recommended protections disabled.
npm ERR! Unexpected token '.'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Freddy\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-10-13T15_25_54_453Z-debug-0.log
```

My system details are:

[image]

My file `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "phantomult",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "oom": "node --max_old_space_size=4096 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng serve"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "^3.0.0-beta.0",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.901.0",
    "@angular/animations": "~9.1.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^9.2.4",
    "@angular/common": "~9.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~9.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^9.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "~9.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~9.1.0",
    "@angular/google-maps": "^10.0.1",
    "@angular/localize": "~9.1.0",
    "@angular/material": "^7.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~9.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~9.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "~9.1.0",
    "@auth0/angular-jwt": "^5.0.1",
    "@aws-amplify/ui-angular": "^0.2.7",
    "@circlon/angular-tree-component": "^10.0.3",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.12.1",
    "@fullcalendar/angular": "^4.4.5-beta",
    "@fullcalendar/resource-timegrid": "^4.4.2",
    "@fullcalendar/resource-timeline": "^4.4.0",
    "@fullcalendar/timegrid": "^4.4.2",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^6.1.0",
    "@ng-select/ng-select": "^4.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^12.1.2",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^5.0.0",
    "@rxjs/rx": "^4.1.0",
    "@tensorflow/tfjs-node-gpu": "^1.7.2",
    "@types/chart.js": "^2.9.13",
    "@types/google.visualization": "0.0.53",
    "@types/hammerjs": "^2.0.36",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.3.38",
    "@types/jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "angular-bootstrap-md": "^9.0.1",
    "angular-google-charts": "^1.1.6",
    "angular-moment": "^1.3.0",
    "angular-ng-autocomplete": "^2.0.1",
    "angular-persistence": "^1.0.1",
    "angular-popper": "^2.0.1",
    "angular-select2-component": "^1.1.4",
    "angular-tag-cloud-module": "^5.2.0",
    "angular8-mat-datepicker": "^1.0.2",
    "angularx-flatpickr": "^6.4.0",
    "animate.css": "^3.7.2",
    "aws-amplify": "^3.0.14",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.688.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.0",
    "core-js": "^3.6.4",
    "currency.js": "^2.0.3",
    "fast-deep-equal": "^3.1.3",
    "flatpickr": "^4.6.3",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "jwt-authn": "^1.1.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "lodash.isequal": "^4.5.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "ng-select2-component": "^7.1.3",
    "ng2-google-charts": "^6.1.0",
    "ng2-right-click-menu": "^1.1.3",
    "ng2-search-filter": "^0.5.1",
    "ngx-captcha": "^8.0.1",
    "ngx-chips": "^2.1.0",
    "ngx-clipboard": "^14.0.1",
    "ngx-image-cropper": "^3.1.9",
    "ngx-infinite-scroll": "^10.0.1",
    "ngx-multi-line-ellipsis": "^1.0.4",
    "ngx-skeleton-loader": "^2.5.0",
    "ngx-webcam": "^0.3.0",
    "node-jose": "^2.0.0",
    "popper.js": "^1.14.0",
    "print-js": "^1.6.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.4",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.6.6",
    "secure-ls": "^1.2.6",
    "sweetalert2": "^9.13.1",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "uuid": "^8.3.0",
    "xlsx": "^0.16.9",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^9.1.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~9.1.0",
    "@types/googlemaps": "^3.39.13",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.10",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^13.13.9",
    "codelyzer": "~5.2.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.1",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "karma": "~4.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~3.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.3",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.8.1",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~3.8.3"
  }
}
```

I have been trying to run the command npm install --force but I still get the same error

Comment: What does the log at `C:\Users\Freddy\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-10-13T15_25_54_453Z-debug-0.log` say? From the error, it sounds like there's a rogue period somewhere but after a quick glance I don't see any glaring problems. Maybe it has to do with your version of node not agreeing with your version of ng? It says your version is unsupported.

Answer (score 0):

First of all i see that you have Angular-Cli: 12.2.9 and in your `package.json` you have 9.1.0.

Update `package.json` with this info:

```js
"devDependencies": {
  "@angular/cli": "^12.2.9",
  "@angular/language-service": "~12.2.9",
  "@types/googlemaps": "^3.39.13",
  "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.10",
  "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
  "@types/node": "^16.7.13",
  "codelyzer": "~6.0.2",
  "jasmine-core": "~3.8.0",
  "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~7.0.0",
  "karma": "~6.3.4",
  "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
  "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.3",
  "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.1",
  "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.7.0",
  "protractor": "~7.0.0",
  "ts-node": "~10.2.1",
  "tslint": "~6.1.3",
  "typescript": "~4.3.5"
}
```

After that i would recommend:

```
npm cache clean --force
```

After that, i would delete the node_modules and package-lock.json and run `npm install`

If that does not work, try to update the versions of npm and angular.

```
npm install -g npm@latest
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

And run the cache clean, delete the packages and run `npm install`

Comment: It's not recommanded to upgrade the version of angular like this. The Update guide is the best way to update is to follow the guide: https://update.angular.io/